# Why lambda does not stop execution

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda

Im building a lambda that calls another lambda in `nodejs` with aws. The problem is that my lambdas should run synchrony and I cant finish it after I call `return callback` function. Im using also `context.callbackWaitsForEmptyEventLoop == false`.

My code gets a list on firebase and executes this list, If lambda timeout reaches 60 secounds or more, it calls another lambda and returns the callback function.

Like that:

```
       return callback(null, {
          statusCode: 400,
          headers: {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'},
          body: JSON.stringify(result)
        })
```

How can I solve this problem?
thanks.

Comment: *"The problem is that my lambdas should run synchrony and I cant finish it after I call return callback function."*  Can you clarify this statment?  What do you mean, you "can't finish it" ...?

Comment: Sorry, My lambda function should stop when initialize other, that is what I mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lambda supports both sync and async invocation type , you can specify `invocation type` as `RequestResponse`.

Please refer [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-prog-model-handler.html)